# OAuth Client Credentials Reissue Access Token vs. Refresh Token

Tags: oauth-2.0, client, access-token, refresh-token

Read through a few similar posts in regards to the purpose of Refresh tokens in Oauth 2 flows, and they make sense for user attended authentication such as username and password, but for the Oauth2 client credentials flow, why risk utilizing a refresh token at all?

Is there less system strain or is it faster to use a refresh token to get a new access token after it has expired as opposed to getting an access token through client id and client secret authentication?

**Posts Referenced:**

- [Why Does OAuth v2 Have Both Access and Refresh Tokens?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3487991/why-does-oauth-v2-have-both-access-and-refresh-tokens)
- [what's the point of refresh token?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10703532/whats-the-point-of-refresh-token?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

The short and skinny is -- the client can act on its own behalf without involving a resource owner; just request a new access token as before.

---

> ...but for the Oauth2 client credentials flow, why risk utilizing a
>   refresh token at all?

Nice observation; the client credentials flow does not issue refresh tokens. Absent a resource owner, it's reasonable to assume the client can request a new access token as needed.

> Is there less system strain or is it faster to use a refresh token to
>   get a new access token after it has expired as opposed to getting an
>   access token through client id and client secret authentication?

While it's certainly implementation specific on how "fast" a refresh token is processed, it's likely marginally slower to process a refresh token over a request for a new access token. This is due to the client being able to directly request an access token which does not require validation of a refresh token against the calling client.