# Node.js - Should I refresh cookie with each request/response to update expiration time?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cookies, jwt

**Authentication method**

In my Node.js (w/ Express.js) back-end, I authenticate users using JWT that is stored in a cookie with `HttpOnly` flag. The cookie expires in *N* hours. A middleware checks if JWT is valid and either calls `next()` function or sends a *401* status.

**Current behavior**

If cookie expires, user must log in again, even if he was still using the app.

**Desired behavior**

I want the cookie to expire in *N* hours but as long as user is using the app, expiration time must be updated. User should log in again only if *N* hours have passed from the last time he interacted with the app.

**Question**

Should I send a new cookie with each response, even if the only thing that changes is expiration time? Is this considered a good practice?

Answer (score 4):

what you need is called **refresh-token**

you can find more detail about refresh tokens on:

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.5 and
https://developer.okta.com/docs/guides/refresh-tokens/main/

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I ended up using a refresh token due to the other benefits it offers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10703532/whats-the-point-of-refresh-token. However, what if someone goes without refresh token? Could he follow the approach I describe?