# Why does YouTube API use refresh token to get the access token?

Tags: youtube, cryptography, youtube-api

Why not use just one for everything? Refresh token doesn't change by default, so why bother to get an access token every hour? API: https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_oauth2#OAuth2_Server_Side_Web_Applications_Flow

Answer (score 2):

They choose that the given access does not last forever: So you need to get a new access token once it has expired. 
The purpose of the refresh token is that you have to ask the user for permission only one time.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [good discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7209263/257141) on the topic.

When you get a refresh token, you also need the client ID and secret. With an access token, you can make API calls using just that. A lot of this comes form learnings from OAuth 1.x, which had a much more complex signing protocol - it just caused lots of bugs and problems with client/server protocol mismatch. Using only an access token made API calls, the *most* important part of OAuth, much easier to implement and maintain.