# In JS web apps, how is it ensured that a malicious user with the access token will not be able to refresh it?

Tags: javascript, security, oauth, oauth-2.0

I find ensuring safety for OAuth with JS apps a̶ ̶p̶a̶i̶n̶ ̶i̶n̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶a̶.̶.̶.̶  very annoying :(

---

Let's imagine I am *Alice*, a legal user, using a **JS single page app client of an OAuth server**. I have logged in and received my tokens (access and refresh).

At some point, unfortunately, my still valid access token and the refresh token are retrieved by a malicious user, *Bob* (note that there is no reason only the refresh token could be retrieved since both are sent back by the OAuth server the same way).

Ok, so what I'm understanding from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3487991/why-does-oauth-v2-have-both-access-and-refresh-tokens) is that, well, that does not matter that much because evil *Bob* will only have a limited amount of time to do bad stuff, since the token has a short life.

Now let's assume the token has expired. In theory, all should be over for *Bob*.

But I do not understand what now prevents *Bob* to request a new token. What does *Alice* has that *Bob* does not so that only *Alice* can get a new access token?

---

Let's now think of slightly different client configuration: there is **still a JS web app**, but this time **the actual OAuth client is a PHP backend** the JS client makes requests to. This PHP back-end acts as a sort of proxy and, as any OAuth client, makes/forwards requests to the OAuth server.

In this case, the refresh token could have been kept secret by the back-end, and *Bob* would have only retrieved the access token. But in this case, again, except from the this now expired access token, that *Bob* do know, what data can *Alice* give the back-end so that it differentiates between her and *Bob* so that the refreshing process is only done for *Alice*?

Answer (score 3):

For JavaScript applications (SPAs), you are supposed to use the [implicit grant](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.2), which does not support refresh tokens. Basically, your users are redirected to the auth server, log in and get the access token. When the access token expires, they need to re-authenticate with the auth server.

Since you can't keep secrets in a JavaScript application, there's no client ID or secret:

> The implicit grant type does not include client authentication, and
> relies on the presence of the resource owner and the registration of
> the redirection URI.

Comment: Thanks. In my case (though I did not mention it in the question) my SPA and the OAuth server are on the same domain and by the same author. I thought Resource Owner Password Credentials would have been the way to go in such a case, since I would have liked to avoid redirections. But this seems complicated with an SPA. By the way how does Facebook to allow for staying connected that long from SPAs with short-life tokens? Some sort of automatic token renewal?