# How a system with JWT authentication refresh_token do horizontal scale out

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, jwt

I'm trying to make my web-app's authentication with JWT.

I chose that because JWT is good for scaling-out (horizontal) the system since we wont need to store anything (such as session data) in server.

I also want to make my login form with "Keep me login" option. Then I found the magic  [refresh_token solution](https://hasura.io/blog/best-practices-of-using-jwt-with-graphql/#silent_refresh).

It's a good solution.

However, I concern how it can accomplish the scale-out purpose? Because, AFAIK, we have to store data about refresh_token in database or something like that.

P.s: I'm new to distribution system if the explanation above is wrong plz help correct me. Thanks

Comment: Instead of rolling your own security, consider looking into existing OAuth2 systems. You shouldn't have to write this.

Comment: @Evert thanks, I will take a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The refresh token is being held by the client, no server-side storage should be needed (unless you are thinking about some "strange" usage scenario). So no horizontal scaling issues. On the server, you only keep client_id and secret (which is env var or similar, so not an obstacle for horizontal scalability).

There's a similar discussion:
[How to securely keep my users signed in with refresh tokens?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32903312/how-to-securely-keep-my-users-signed-in-with-refresh-tokens)

*Edit due discussion in comments*. The server validates access token always (if it's not expired, if a signature is valid, if the whitelisted issuer, if contains the required scope, etc.). A refresh token is used to request a new access token when the old one is expired, that's its only purpose.

And yes server needs some data for validation, but it's provided by the OAuth2 service provider through a .well-known endpoint or similar. So the server needs to be able to communicate with a service provider to be able to fetch the info required for validation.

Those .well-known endpoints are usually public, for example:

- https://www.facebook.com/.well-known/openid-configuration/
- https://accounts.google.com/.well-known/openid-configuration

Comment: *something* will need to store the refresh token on the server, because otherwise how can the server know it's valid?

Comment: @Evert question was about was to store it to keep user logged in - from user/system side, not how oauth2 service provider validates it.

Comment: @GintautasKišonas sorry for confusing you. Actually, my question is about validating the refresh_token same as Evert commented. As I understand, on the server, we should store something about refresh_token to validate it from client's request. So each server will have different data about refresh_token of 1 user. And i feel it's hard for scale-out same as session-cookie authentication. Or there is other solution to do that, plz tell me

Comment: Edited answer elaborating purpose of refresh token - you request a new access token by passing refresh token to oauth2 service provider. You should not interpret it in any way, it's just stored as the ticket to extend your visit

Comment: @GintautasKišonas your assumption was that there was an existing OAuth2 server, but unfortunately for many new JWT implementors everyone reinvents the wheel.

Comment: @Evert ok agree that didn't come to my mind that someone might want to implement their own OAuth2 service provider when there are plenty of free SaaS or selfhosted ones

Comment: @GintautasKišonas thanks, could you suggest me the keywords to find these "there are plenty of free SaaS or selfhosted ones"?

Comment: Y sure. Keywords would be identity management and OIDC. Unfortunately, Google search yields a lot of intermediates or highly-priced enterprise-grade results. I personally can recommend Auth0 and Firebase as free ones and Azure Active Directory as cheap one. If you want to self-host it - IdentityServer is the best from what I have tried. Any major platform usually has one - I have tried some implementation on top of Django for example - well it works for some basic use cases, but overall self-hosted is a bumpy ride. Would generally recommend starting with Auth0 - it's both easy and versatile.

Comment: @GintautasKišonas thank you very much, I will try them