# Google Play Developer API - Query purchase token returns Invalid Value

Tags: java, google-play

I am trying to set up a web service to query Google Play purchases.  We store the order information for customers and this service would call Google Play API to query the subscription details.

Every time i try to query a purchase, it gives me the error:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
{  
   "error":{  
      "errors":[  
         {  
            "domain":"global",
            "reason":"invalid",
            "message":"Invalid Value"
         }
      ],
      "code":400,
      "message":"Invalid Value"
   }
}
```

Here is what I tried:

- Created a project in https://console.developers.google.com enabled the "Google Play Android Developer API"
- Created an oAuth 2.0 client_id and client_secret for type Web application
- Logged in as the account owner, I generated a refresh_token
- In https://play.google.com/apps/publish I went to Settings -> API Access and linked the the project to my app

Code wise, I used the refresh_token to get an access_token:

```
String refreshToken = "1/ljll6d9ME3Uc13jMrBweqXugV4g4timYcXXXXXXXXX";
HttpPost request = new HttpPost("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token");
List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("client_id", client_id));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("client_secret", client_secret));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("refresh_token", refreshToken));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("grant_type", "refresh_token"));
request.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
String body = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(body);
String accessToken = json.getString("access_token");
```

The access_token from this works because i can call this API with it and get the response back:

```
String url = String.format("https://www.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v2/applications/%s/inappproducts/%s", packageName, productId);
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet get = new HttpGet(url);
get.setHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
HttpResponse response = client.execute(get);
// parse response etc...
```

This returns:

```
{  
    "packageName":"com.my.app",
    "sku":"com.my.app.premium",
    "status":"active",
    "purchaseType":"subscription",
    "defaultPrice":{  
    //...
}
},
    "listings":{  
    "en-US":{  
    "title":"My App Premium",
    "description":"My App"
}
},
    "defaultLanguage":"en-US",
    "subscriptionPeriod":"P1Y"
}
```

Now, I want to get informatoin about a purchase.  I have a information from a purchase as such:

```
{  
"orderId":"GPA.1111-1111-1111-11111",
"packageName":"com.my.app",
"productId":"com.my.app.premium",
"purchaseTime":1452801843877,
"purchaseState":0,
"developerPayload":"XXXXXXXd9261023a407ae5bb6ab8XXXXXXX",
"purchaseToken":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.YY-J123o12-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxmYRk2itBkNdlXhyLMjXsxxxxxxxxxxxxLfBxabaAjKbeBC0PVhHnHd1DDbFkgZtbQxxk5pDIAH3xBHu8HrcWfRgewAYnFeW9xxxxxxxxxxxxxC5TDjcBL8fhf",
"autoRenewing":true
}

String url = String.format("https://www.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v2/applications/%s/purchases/products/%s/tokens/%s",packageName, productId, purchaseToken);
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet get = new HttpGet(url);
get.setHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
HttpResponse response = client.execute(get);
// parse response etc...
```

Since the packageName / productId and access_token seem to work for the first call, and the purchaseToken is right out of the order info.  What is giving the invalid value error?

Any help appreciated - not sure what else to try.  Thanks!

UPDATE:
I went through and validated all the package names and account setup
The real issue seemed to be the service i was hitting.  I switched it to:
https://www.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v2/applications/packageName/purchases/subscriptions/subscriptionId/tokens/purchaseToken

I also swapped to use the Google Client API as it was much cleaner looking that manually creating requests.

Thanks for help and replies

Comment: Same problem here, did you figure it out?

Comment: Same problem here, did you solve it ?@Fid @Antoine . step by the first answer, I have the same error.

Comment: I think my payload was not correct but I can't remember which part exactly.

Comment: Saved my day! Also need to change the url to "subscriptions".

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 13):

> First I want to share with you what is **400 bad request** and what is the
>   real cause for occuring it?

**Ans:** It indicates that the query was invalid. E.g., parent ID was missing or the combination of dimensions or metrics requested was not valid.

**Recommended Action:** You need to make changes to the API query in order for it to work.

**Resource Link:** [Standard Error Responses](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/coreErrors#standard_errors)

### Your problem:

Your code was running properly and returning related `json` file as output. But after a period,`it is not working when you want to get information about purchase`. It gives error message **"HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request"**

### Root cause:

For refresh token, the response always includes a new access token. A response is shown below:

```
{
  "access_token":"1/fFBGRNJru1FQd44AzqT3ZgXXXXXX",
  "expires_in":3920,
  "token_type":"Bearer",
}
```

So, access token has a expiry time. after a expiry time, the access token will not work.

There is another restriction also. There are limits on the number of refresh tokens that will be issued; one limit per client/user combination, and another per user across all clients.

So, in your case, **you have already crossed your limit of creating refresh token.**

### Solution:

So, you first need to revoke the token. Then save refresh tokens in long-term storage and continue to use them as long as they remain valid.

As you are using refresh token, then you need to change the http post request `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token`  to `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token`

So your code will be look like below:

```
String refreshToken = "1/ljll6d9ME3Uc13jMrBweqXugV4g4timYcXXXXXXXXX";
HttpPost request = new HttpPost("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token");
List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
...............
...............
```

### Revoking procedure:

There are 2 ways for revoking.

1. A user can revoke access by visiting [Account Settings](https://security.google.com/settings/security/permissions)
2. It is also possible for an application to programmatically revoke the access given to it.

To programmatically revoke a token, your application makes a request to `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/revoke` and includes the token as a parameter:

```
curl https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/revoke?token={token}
```

The `token` can be an access token or a refresh token. If the token is an access token and it has a corresponding refresh token, the refresh token will also be revoked.

> N.B: If the revocation is successfully processed, then the status code
>   of the response is 200. For error conditions, a status code 400 is
>   returned along with an error code.

### Resource Link:

1. [Offline access, Using refresh token and Revoke a token](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#offline)

Comment: hi ~ @SkyWalker,  I use your method, but have same error, has anything else to try ?

Comment: @wawa Please check my another answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36266696/2293534 and have a look this tutorial: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2#basicsteps. Hope it will clarify your concept.

Comment: hi~ @SkyWalker, check your two answer carefully, but I still get error:"error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "invalid",
    "message": "Invalid Value"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Invalid Value"
 }
what should I do?

Comment: @wawa I think it it token expiration issue. So, I have some questions

`1. Have you revoked your token yet?
2. Have your token not used more than 6 months?
3. Have you changed your password?
4. How much time you have token request? If it already over 25 times, creating a new token automatically invalidates the oldest token without warning.`

Another way: If possible, for testing purpose only, you can create a new token with new mail and check that if it is working properly or not.

You can read Token Expiration:https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2#expiration

Comment: hi~ @SkyWalker thank you for your reply.I revoke my refresh_token and create new refresh_token ,then create new access_token, and then request purchase info, also return "400 Invalid Value".I haven't changed my password and hasn't over 25 times also.

Comment: Would you please check with new mail id for confirmation...that it works fine.Check it from here https://support.google.com/a/#topic=29157 @wawa

Comment: @wawa Checking Procedure --**without refresh token:-**

`1. send API request with access token
2. if access token is invalid, fail and ask user to re-authenticate`
**with refresh token:-**
`1. send API request with access token
2. If access token is invalid, try to update it using refresh token
3. if refresh request passes, update the access token and re-send the initial API request
4. If refresh request fails, ask user to re-authenticate` For more: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12885823/2293534

Comment: hi~ @SkyWalker, my order's itemType is subs, Is it possible this order have no Purchases.products value? I can get the order's Purchases.subscriptions value.

Answer (score 3):

This happened to me when I was testing with Static Responses, i.e. using reserved product IDs for testing (like `android.test.purchased`). SkyWalker's solution did not help in this case.

Then I used real product IDs, published my app as alpha to google play and side-loaded the release apk into my device and now everything works as expected.

Be sure to read carefully chapter [Setting Up for Test Purchases](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html) in google docs to prepare your app and account properly for testing.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this to see API request and response. Need help with the [API Explorer](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/archive/v1_1/purchases/get?)

```
API: https://www.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v1.1/applications/packageName/subscriptions/subscriptionId/purchases/token
```

Request parameters:

> packageName:PACKAGE_NAME
>
> subscriptionId:SUBSCRIPTION_ID
>
> token:PURCHASE_TOKEN