# Query purchase products info returns Invalid Value use Google Play Developer API

Tags: google-play

this problem may be similar [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35019357/google-play-developer-api-query-purchase-token-returns-invalid-value), but some different

1、I get client_id client_secret by [this](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/getting_started)

2、I get authorization_code by:
`https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/androidpublisher&response_type=code&access_type=offline&redirect_uri={REDIRECT_URIS}&client_id={CLIENT_ID}`

3、get refresh_token by:

```
urls := "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token"

postData := "redirect_uri=%s&grant_type=authorization_code&client_id=%s&client_secret=%s&code=%s"
postData = fmt.Sprintf(postData, url.QueryEscape(REDIRECT_URL), url.QueryEscape(CLIENT_ID), url.QueryEscape(CLIENT_SECRET), url.QueryEscape(CODE))
beego.Debug("postData:", postData)

body, err := service.Post(urls, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", bytes.NewReader([]byte(postData)))
```

4、I get access_token by:

```
urls := "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token"

postData := "grant_type=refresh_token&client_id=%s&client_secret=%s&refresh_token=%s"
postData = fmt.Sprintf(postData, url.QueryEscape(CLIENT_ID), url.QueryEscape(CLIENT_SECRET), url.QueryEscape(REFRESH_TOKEN))
beego.Debug("postData:", postData)

body, err := service.Post(urls, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", bytes.NewReader([]byte(postData)))
```

and I want get products info:

```
urls := "https://www.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v2/applications/%s/purchases/products/%s/tokens/%s"
urls = fmt.Sprintf(urls, url.QueryEscape("cn.wps.moffice_premium"), url.QueryEscape("premium_sub_m"), url.QueryEscape("fngalnikxxxxxxcncnbfa.AO-J1OxEoo9RnI-tFqxxxxxxB6u-xbsnp74QYZQYsw_yDyLxxxxxxxaAohBFeafRTZBIioiljUt_ZVbexxxxxxPV7jD_QPQTpmftxpoQGzGloApv9mJnxBe5thDxxxxxxxLhpRRRWlK"))
header := http.Header{}
header.Add("Authorization", "Bearer "+accessToken)
body, err := service.Get(urls, header)
```

and I get err:

```
 {
 "error": {
 "errors": [
  {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "invalid",
    "message": "Invalid Value"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Invalid Value"
 }
}
```

I try this url can return valid value:

```
"https://www.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v2/applications/%s/purchases/subscriptions/%s/tokens/%s"
```

not sure what else to try.
Thanks for help and replies

Answer (score 4):

I find the reason. My order item type is "subs", so can't use this [Purchases.products](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/purchases/products/get)
I use order item type "inapp", use Purchases.products return 200.