# Google Play Developer API - 400 Invalid Value - InAppPurchases

Tags: java, kotlin, google-oauth, google-api-java-client, google-play-developer-api

My question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35019357/google-play-developer-api-query-purchase-token-returns-invalid-value). However, I am using the [API Java Client Library](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/androidpublisher/v2) with a service account, making calls to the API from my server.

My code is following [this](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount) guide, which is very simple. However, I can't seem to get an appropriate error for my request. This is how I build my `AndroidPublisher`:

```
val credential = GoogleCredential.fromStream(FileInputStream(
        "/path/to/json"
)).createScoped(Collections.singleton(AndroidPublisherScopes.ANDROIDPUBLISHER))

androidPublisher = AndroidPublisher.Builder(httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
        .setApplicationName(packageName)
        .build()
```

Where the JSON is generated from the Developer Console, under Service Accounts. This is how I make my request:

```
androidPublisher.purchases().subscriptions().get(packageName, "valid-sku", "invalid-token").execute()
```

My subscription ID is valid but my token is invalid. I expect an error such as "invalid token" in the response. However, what I get is:

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 400 Bad Request
{
  "code" : 400,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Invalid Value",
    "reason" : "invalid"
  } ],
  "message" : "Invalid Value"
}
```

Is that a generic error because of the invalid token or is it an authentication issue? If it an authentication issue, how do I solve it? If it is an invalid token issue, how am I supposed to know?

**Some more information:**

- I get the same error when trying to make that call from the API Explorer as well (this time using a Client ID and API Key instead of Service Account).
- I have **not** delegated domain-wide access to the service account. Do I have to for some reason?
- I can successfully make **other calls** to the API such as [`inappproducts.list`](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/inappproducts/list)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So, the reason that happened was just because the `purchaseToken` I was using was wrong.

I did not expect that to be the reason as I thought that in the case of an invalid token, I would receive a "token invalid" error (or something similar). As it turns out, the responses given by Google are pretty inconsistent (a 404 could also be given for an invalid token).

Comment: Could you please tell me what makes a purchase token invalid?!!
If this is really the case, I can't understand why it is considered invalid while it is generated from the built-in google play billing library included in my Android application !!

Answer (score 13):

From my experiences, if you have `HTTP 400` error with `Invalid Value` then that purchase or subscription is **FRAUD**.

You can check out Order Id part of those purchases. Probably in the format of `XXXXXXXXXXXX.XXXXXXXXXXXX` which is wrong and should be `GPA.XXXX.XXXXX.XXXXX.XXX`

- I don't really count the X char number. I just added to show the logic.

Comment: Do you have any idea how users get this fraudulent Order ID?

Comment: @JoeOkatch there are several ways for that. Since they are not legal I will not share the links directly. However you can google it as "How can we h..k the in-app purchases in Google Play Store?" You will come up something like; "Patcher"

Comment: @BerkatTuranci very much appreciated. I have been getting these fraudulent codes lately. We are always learning something new.

Comment: @BerkatTuranci also another question if you don't mind...Is it normal for the console to indicate orders as "charged 0" even though api json is OK?

Comment: @JoeOkatch if you are using subscription and allow free usage trial time then it is okay. For the first trial period you can see 0 price for charged. And normal payment for the second recurrence.

Comment: @BerkatTuranci Oh, I see. I just realised that we left the free trial mode on in the console. Much appreciated.

Comment: @BerkayTurancı where I can see order id?

Comment: @glinda93 you can check out from Play Store Console Payment page; https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2741495?hl=en#zippy=%2Cusing-the-play-console-website or from the Play Store Payment API Order Id part; https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/rest/v3/purchases.subscriptions

Comment: thanks for this, I got exactly what you described and was pondering for a little bit, where there was no new subscirption in the console and order id was different

Answer (score 12):

In my case the problem was that I was calling:

```
purchases.products.get
```

Instead of:

```
purchases.subscriptions.get
```

Comment: So hilarious! How come I didn't notice it haha. Google docs maze could have misled me.

Answer (score 6):

Scratched my head for a few hours, ALL my parameters were correct, and then well.. I realized that I was barking up the wrong tree (endpoint)

```
https://androidpublisher.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v3/applications/{packageName}/purchases/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/tokens/{token}
```

is not this

```
https://androidpublisher.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v3/applications/{packageName}/purchases/products/{productId}/tokens/{token}
```

/purchases/subscriptions/.. vs  /purchases/products/..

Comment: I can't believe I've spent several days trying to debug this issue, and THIS is the answer that solves it for me... In any case, much appreciated!

Answer (score -1):

For all those who run into this problem, 99% of you need to publish the application for internal testers.

Follow this guide: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6062777?hl=en

[image]

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/28546688)

Comment: You're right, I changed my answer, I hope to help someone in the future, it took me a long time to find this solution.