# Google play console orders charged 0

Tags: android, subscription

We've just launched our subscription-based app. We did thorough testing and everything was OK. However, when we lauched the production version something seems wrong. We have received purchases from users and validated them via the Google Play Developer Api and every purchase seems OK. But, if I go to Publisher Play Console > "Financial Reports > Subscriptions" it indicates that there is no revenue.

Checking on the Play Console mobile App indicates that the orders are there but they are shown as ***"The customer's payment was successfully charged $0"***, all of them. I can't seem to find any literature on the internet that could point me to what's wrong or what we are missing.

Can somebody advise me if we missed a step along the way?

Answer (score 2):

So after some more digging we realised that we didn't disable the **Free Trial** in Google Play Console. We removed it and it worked well. The orders that were charged "0" eventually got billed the right amount after their trial was over.

We also got a lot of help from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46055214/google-play-developer-api-400-invalid-value-inapppurchases/55986586) with regards to some fraudulent transactions.