# Difference between refresh_token and access_token

Tags: asp.net-web-api, token, jwt

> I can't find any reason why to use **refresh_token**. when we can make
>   **access_token** longed lived...
>
> Why do we have both?

Answer (score 8):

As you have `JWT` as a tag on your question I will assume you are referring to `Json Web Tokens`

The following was referenced from

[Refresh Tokens: When to Use Them and How They Interact with JWTs](https://auth0.com/blog/2015/10/07/refresh-tokens-what-are-they-and-when-to-use-them/)

> - **Access tokens** carry the necessary information to access a resource directly. In other words, when a client passes an access
>     token to a server managing a resource, that server can use the
>     information contained in the token to decide whether the client is
>     authorized or not. **Access tokens usually have an expiration date and
>     are short-lived**.
> - **Refresh tokens** carry the information necessary to get a new access token. In other words, whenever an access token is required to
>     access a specific resource, a client may use a refresh token to get a
>     new access token issued by the authentication server. Common use cases
>     include getting new access tokens after old ones have expired, or
>     getting access to a new resource for the first time. Refresh tokens
>     can also expire but are rather long-lived. Refresh tokens are usually
>     subject to strict storage requirements to ensure they are not leaked.
>     They can also be blacklisted by the authorization server.

This second reference is also an interesting read re the short-lived access token and  long-lived refresh token.
[Why Does OAuth v2 Have Both Access and Refresh Tokens?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12885823/5233410)

> **revocation:** if the access token is self contained, authorization can be revoked by not issuing new access tokens. A resource does not
>   need to query the authorization server to see if the access token is
>   valid.This simplifies access token validation and makes it easier to
>   scale and support multiple authorization servers. There is a window of
>   time when an access token is valid, but authorization is revoked.

Hope this helps.