# If token expiry time for third party api is short ,how can I scale the third party token generation, client id and secret is stored on my database

Tags: token, scaling

I am trying to upload CSV in third party FTP application and creating record from that csv into my system.User can access my application on demand.Each user has its own client id and secret for this third party apis.

Comment: Could your provide more context? like the technologies being involved . its hard to answer the question as the answer depends on the services being used (especially the third party)

Comment: You might want to check other questions like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38986005/what-is-the-purpose-of-a-refresh-token

Comment: I am using box api's for the application