# OAUTH2 Refresh Token

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, zend-framework2, laminas-api-tools, refresh-token

I am little confuse of Refresh Token in OAuth2. 
Like it says access token limit the time window of 1 hour that hacker can use the user credentials and refresh token is long live token which can be use to recreate the access token.

I am confused if someone stole the access token from cookie he can also stole the refresh token and can use the refresh token to create new access token as I have ajax request in JQuery (Client Side)

**NOTE:** I have created ajax request to send refresh token on server side I append the Client ID and Secret there with grant type refresh token.

I have saved both access token and refresh token in cookie and use following the ajax request to get new access token

```
jQuery(document).ajaxError(function(event, jqXHR, ajaxSettings, thrownError) {

        //console.log('event');console.log(event);
        //console.log('jqXHR');console.log(jqXHR);
        //console.log('ajaxSettings');console.log(ajaxSettings);
        //console.log('thrownError');console.log(thrownError);

        if(jqXHR.status == 403)
        {
            console.log('User is not Loged in Redictet to Login Page');
        }   

        if(jqXHR.status == 401)
        {
            var refresh_token = Cookies.get('refresh_token');
            if(refresh_token != undefined)
            {
                $.ajax({
                        url: CONNECT_API_URL+'/refresh-token',
                        type: "POST",
                        data:{ refresh_token: refresh_token },
                        success: function(response, status, jqXHR){
                            if(response.access_token != undefined)
                            {
                                var expires_in = new Date(new Date().getTime() + response.expires_in * 1000);
                var access_token = response.token_type+' '+response.access_token;
                Cookies.set('access_token', access_token, { expires: expires_in });
                Cookies.set('refresh_token', response.refresh_token, { expires: 14 });
                                $.ajax(ajaxSettings); // Re send same ajax request with access token in cookie has been set
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                console.log('Redirect to login page.');
                            }
                        }, 
                 });    
            }
        }   


});
```

How should I used refresh token to enhance the security?

Comment: Can you please tell as to which grant flow of Oauth2 are you using in the application? Also , do mentioned if this is a single page application or server side rendering or a mobile application?

Comment: Notice OAuth2 must be used with SSL/TLS (HTTPS)  to encrypt the communication channel from the client to the server.

Comment: Actually this the web application Consuming REST API  Services I am using OAuth2 grant_type Password.

Comment: @ViníciusFagundes Even that it is HTTPS but I assume there may be some XSS so the attacker can get the cookies refresh token and access token in that case how refresh token help to make more secure

Comment: @vaya I have made REST Service which get username password from user and on server end I append ClientId and secret with password grant type

Comment: Why do you want to store the Refresh token on the client side? Your client id and client secret is on the server side, so why not store the refresh token in server side, associated to the current access token. On client side, when the access token is expired, you can send a request to server to get the token reissued with the help of refresh token. The advantage is to have a refresh token is to have a short lived access token

Answer (score 1):

Here on this blog post with the title [**Refresh Tokens: When to Use Them and How They Interact with JWTs**](https://auth0.com/blog/refresh-tokens-what-are-they-and-when-to-use-them/) the topic from your question is nicely discussed.

A quote from that post:

> Refresh tokens are usually subject to strict storage requirements to ensure they are not leaked.

In the [RFC6819 spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6819#section-5.1.6) they write the following about storing access tokens on the client:

> **5.1.6.  Access Tokens**

> The following measures should be used to protect access tokens:

> - Keep them in transient memory (accessible by the client
>   application only).
> - Pass tokens securely using secure transport (TLS).
> - Ensure that client applications do not share tokens with 3rd
>   parties.

And about the issuance of refresh tokens:

> **5.2.2.1.  Restricted Issuance of Refresh Tokens**

> The authorization server may decide, based on an appropriate policy,
> not to issue refresh tokens.  Since refresh tokens are long-term
> credentials, they may be subject to theft.  For example, if the
> authorization server does not trust a client to securely store such
> tokens, it may refuse to issue such a client a refresh token.

This means you should probably think carefully on where you want to store your refresh tokens. This post [**Where to Store your JWTs – Cookies vs HTML5 Web Storage**](https://stormpath.com/blog/where-to-store-your-jwts-cookies-vs-html5-web-storage) deals with exactly this topic.

As also mentioned [in this answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7209263/1697459) only the `refresh_token` is not enough to get a new `access_token`.

> Refresh tokens, if compromised, are useless because the attacker requires the client id and secret in addition to the refresh token in order to gain an access token.

This can also be found in that same [RFC6819 spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6819#section-5.2.2.2):

> **5.2.2.2.  Binding of Refresh Token to "client_id"**

> The authorization server should match every refresh token to the
> identifier of the client to whom it was issued.  The authorization
> server should check that the same "client_id" is present for every
> request to refresh the access token.  If possible (e.g., confidential
> clients), the authorization server should authenticate the respective
> client.

> This is a countermeasure against refresh token theft or leakage.

Refresh tokens should be used only once. When the `refresh_token` is used it will return a new `access_token` and a new `refresh_token`. It renders the old `refresh_token` useless meaning it can no longer be used.

It also allows the authentication server to recognize that a `refresh_token` was compromised, since it should only be used once. If a new renew request with the same `refresh_token` comes in the authentication server knows there is something fishy going on. Not sure what is the proper way for the server to deal with such a scenario though... (maybe someone else can shine some light on this)

This is also in the [RFC6819 spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6819#section-5.2.2.3):

> **5.2.2.3.  Refresh Token Rotation**

> Refresh token rotation is intended to automatically detect and
> prevent attempts to use the same refresh token in parallel from
> different apps/devices.  This happens if a token gets stolen from the
> client and is subsequently used by both the attacker and the
> legitimate client.  The basic idea is to change the refresh token
> value with every refresh request in order to detect attempts to
> obtain access tokens using old refresh tokens.  Since the
> authorization server cannot determine whether the attacker or the
> legitimate client is trying to access, in case of such an access
> attempt the valid refresh token and the access authorization
> associated with it are both revoked.

> The OAuth specification supports this measure in that the token's
> response allows the authorization server to return a new refresh
> token even for requests with grant type "refresh_token".

> Note: This measure may cause problems in clustered environments,
> since usage of the currently valid refresh token must be ensured.  In
> such an environment, other measures might be more appropriate.

Your access and refresh tokens can be compromised on the client but the tokens could also be intercepted somewhere in between your client and the server.
The `refresh_token` is sent only once to a client while the `access_token` is being sent to the server with every request, that is why the chances of a man-in-the-middle getting his hands on your `access_token` are much bigger then the chance that your `refresh_token` is compromised.

In general it is good to fully understand the OAuth2 protocol so that you can properly implement it. About the security I would say in short:

- A **first demand** for using JWTs is a properly configured https connection between your client and the server so that all the tokens are properly encrypted when they are sent back and forth.
- A **second demand** is that you store the tokens in a secure way on your client.

---

*I hope this gives you some insight on this topic. If someone wants to add or correct my post please feel free to edit/update/compliment the answer or leave a comment.*