# How JWT token lifetime in Spring boot actually works

Tags: spring, oauth-2.0, jwt

I have implemented Oauth2.0 using JWT token until it seems to be basically worked with Spring Boot.

**Question1 :** I can call this URL in order to get 'access_token' and 'refresh_token' as a response.

```
https://myapp/oauth/token?grant_type=password&username=______&password=_______
```

But when every time I re-called the url, **both** access_token and refresh_token were **regenerated** and the **old** access_token **can still be used** until it expired. 
Is it how it really works? 
Regenerate both every time?

**Question2 :** Moreover, when I need to refresh my access_token, I called this URL

```
 https://myapp/oauth/token?grant_type=password&username=______&password=_______
```

I, again, got **both** new access_token and **new refresh_token**. It is pretty strange for me that refresh_token was used to generate a newer refresh_token. But the old refresh_token can still works?!

If this already what JWT token should really work, please tell me why we need refresh_token when we can call the first URL to get new token anyway.

I have spent sometime on this but still could not find a clear reference mentioning these things. 
If you could tell me the right flow that it should work I would appreciate that.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why Does OAuth v2 Have Both Access and Refresh Tokens?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3487991/why-does-oauth-v2-have-both-access-and-refresh-tokens)

Comment: So someone please answer my Question2. It is pretty strange for me that refresh_token was used to generate a newer refresh_token. But the old refresh_token can still works?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding Question 2: yes, you get a new access_token and refresh_token.
It's up to you (or whoever is responsible for the RefreshTokenProvider) that the resfresh_token can only be used once.
This blog article: http://bitoftech.net/2014/07/16/enable-oauth-refresh-tokens-angularjs-app-using-asp-net-web-api-2-owin/ (scroll down to step 6) shows an example.