# Google Sheets java sdk oAuth unauthorized after some hours (spring boot)

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-sheets-api

I successfully created a spring boot Serviceclass in order to write on google sheets, following the [Java Quistart Tutorial for Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/java)

My problem is that the authorization is not renewing, so after the first successful authentication via browser, after some hours I get 401 unauthorized.
How can I automatically renew the token without re-issuing the browser login?

Below the code, thanks in advance

```
import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.jetty.auth.oauth2.LocalServerReceiver;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.jetty.auth.oauth2.LocalServerReceiver.Builder;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleClientSecrets;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.util.store.FileDataStoreFactory;
import com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.Sheets;
import com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.SheetsScopes;
import com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.model.AppendValuesResponse;
import com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.model.ValueRange;

@Service
public class GoogleSheetsServiceImpl implements GoogleSheetsService {

    private static final Log LOGGER = LogFactory.getLog(GoogleSheetsServiceImpl.class);

    /** Application name. */
    @Value("${google-sheets.application-name}")
    private String applicationName;

    /** Directory to store user credentials for this application. */
    private static final java.io.File DATA_STORE_DIR = new java.io.File(System.getProperty("user.home"),
            ".credentials/sheets.googleapis.com-orders");

    /** Global instance of the {@link FileDataStoreFactory}. */
    private FileDataStoreFactory dataStoreFactory;

    /** Global instance of the JSON factory. */
    private JsonFactory jsonFactory;

    /** Global instance of the HTTP transport. */
    private HttpTransport httpTransport;

    /**
     * Global instance of the scopes required by this quickstart.
     *
     * If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials at
     * ~/.credentials/sheets.googleapis.com-java-quickstart
     */
    private List<String> scopes;

    /** Sheet service. */
    private Sheets sheetsService;

    public GoogleSheetsServiceImpl() throws Throwable {
        // init
        try {
            this.jsonFactory = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
            this.scopes = Arrays.asList(SheetsScopes.SPREADSHEETS);
            this.httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
            this.dataStoreFactory = new FileDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_DIR);
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            LOGGER.error("Error on init Google Sheets Service: " + t.getMessage());
            throw t;
        }

        // get sheet service
        Credential credential = this.authorize();
        this.sheetsService = new Sheets.Builder(this.httpTransport, this.jsonFactory, credential)
                .setApplicationName(this.applicationName).build();
    }

    public void appendValueRangeToGoogleSheet(String spreadsheetId, String range, ValueRange valueRange)
            throws IOException {

        // append line
        Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.Append request = sheetsService.spreadsheets().values()
                .append(spreadsheetId, range, valueRange).setValueInputOption("RAW");
        AppendValuesResponse response = request.execute();
    }

    /**
     * Creates an authorized Credential object.
     * 
     * @return an authorized Credential object.
     * @throws IOException
     */
    private Credential authorize() throws IOException {
        // Load client secrets.
        InputStream in = GoogleSheetsServiceImpl.class.getResourceAsStream("/google_sheets/client_secret.json");
        GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(this.jsonFactory, new InputStreamReader(in));

        // Build flow and trigger user authorization request.
        GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(this.httpTransport, this.jsonFactory,
                clientSecrets, this.scopes).setDataStoreFactory(this.dataStoreFactory).setAccessType("online").build();
        LocalServerReceiver.Builder localServerReceiverBuilder = new Builder();
        localServerReceiverBuilder.setHost("localhost");
        localServerReceiverBuilder.setPort(46228);
        Credential credential = new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, localServerReceiverBuilder.build())
                .authorize("user");
        LOGGER.info("Credentials saved to " + DATA_STORE_DIR.getAbsolutePath());
        return credential;
    }

}
```

Edit:

Solved modifying the build of GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow object as follow:

```
GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(this.httpTransport, this.jsonFactory,
            clientSecrets, this.scopes).setDataStoreFactory(this.dataStoreFactory).setAccessType("offline")
                    .setApprovalPrompt("force")
                    .addRefreshListener(
                            new DataStoreCredentialRefreshListener(credentialUserId, this.dataStoreFactory))
                    .build();
```

Comment: I think the guys at https://www.draw.io might have the same issue (based on my experience as user)

Comment: Am i using the wrong approach? I tried to check how to do with Api-Key but i didn't find any example

Comment: I don't know the answer. I will start a bounty on this question to get more attention from other people who may know it

Comment: I'm actually ge4tting 401 Unathorized in the first attempt...How can I be sure I've got the right JSON file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a concept named refresh token and it seems like it suits to your needs.

You can find well discribe in this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7209263/4988996

Edit: According to your comment I found that google has DataStoreCredentialRefreshListener

> Access protected resources using the Credential. Expired access tokens are automatically refreshed using the refresh token, if applicable. Make sure to use DataStoreCredentialRefreshListener and set it for the credential using Credential.Builder.addRefreshListener(CredentialRefreshListener).

Checkout: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-oauth-java-client/oauth2

```java
  static void addDataStoreCredentialRefreshListener(
      Credential.Builder credentialBuilder, String userId, DataStoreFactory dataStoreFactory)
      throws IOException {
    credentialBuilder.addRefreshListener(
        new DataStoreCredentialRefreshListener(userId, dataStoreFactory));
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, do you know if there is any example ready with google sheets java sdk?

Comment: Edited the answer according to your comment. Have a look.

Comment: @user4330585 Have you tried this solution? Any feedback? The bounty expires today

Comment: Thanks @MarioTrucco and Furkan, i am still playing with the code suggested with no luck, trying to understand why

Comment: @user4330585 I didn't have time to try any of this. The answer doesn't look perfect but I'll probabilly award the bounty because it's the best available

Comment: I checked it as accepted answer. I had to add also a modification on the he build of GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow, but the answer helped me to find the solution. Thanks a lot!