# Why don't APIs use access token instead of refresh token?

Tags: api, oauth, oauth-2.0, rest-security

I've already seen

> [Why Does OAuth v2 Have Both Access and Refresh Tokens?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3487991/why-does-oauth-v2-have-both-access-and-refresh-tokens)
>
> https://auth0.com/blog/refresh-tokens-what-are-they-and-when-to-use-them/

As per my understanding, this is how OAuth v2 works:

1) user sends his credentials to the server which validates it and returns an `access_token` and a `refresh_token`

2) user sends this `acsess_token` along with further requests to identify himself

3) when the `access_token` expires, the user sends another request to the server with `refresh_token` and other required parameters asking for a new `access_token` and `refresh_token`

Here's my question:

**What's the need of a separate `refresh_token` ? Why not send the old `access_token` ( *which is about to be expired anyway* ), for a new one ??**

What's the additional advantage of using a `refresh_token` ?

Answer (score 2):

The access token is, in theory, more in play. It could be in a browser, on the server-side of a client, on the authorization server or on a resource server. The access token will be attached to every API request whereas the refresh token should be used much less frequently.

A couple quotations from the web...

Unlike access tokens, refresh tokens are intended for use only with authorization servers and are never sent to resource servers.
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-10.4

[Refresh tokens] are usually subject to strict storage requirements to ensure they are not leaked.
https://auth0.com/learn/refresh-tokens/

Basically, if we only had access token, the attack surface would be greater.