# Spotify API Authorization gives me different refresh token each time

Tags: java, api, spotify

I follow the steps in the Spotify [Web Api Tutorial](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/quick-start/) using the authorization-code from the Spotify Accounts Authentication Examples. Everything is okey, I register an application with Spotify, authenticate a user and get authorization to access user data and when the page show me the user data the refresh token is different each time I authenticate myself. I think refresh token shuld not change.

The only modification I did in the example code was replace the client id, client secret and the redirect uri with the correct values from my application.

Any advices?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why Does OAuth v2 Have Both Access and Refresh Tokens?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3487991/why-does-oauth-v2-have-both-access-and-refresh-tokens)

Comment: @NikolaiShevchenko Thanks for the reference. That's what I said, the refresh token should be the same, but every time I ask Spotify for a refresh token with the same account it gives me a new refresh token. I'm doing something wrong I know...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the **Authorisation Code Flow** you just need to do that initial authentication you're already doing. It will always return a new refresh token however that token can be used over an over with **4. Requesting a refreshed access token; Spotify returns a new access token to your app** from [Authorisation Guide](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization-guide/) that will return you a new access token for subsequent calls and you won't need to do the Authentication Step you're doing multiple times just keep doing that one.