# what is the difference of refresh token and access token in auth 2.0

Tags: authentication

Now I want to generate a access token and a refresh token, but when I do it. I just wonder what the difference of refresh token and access token? or can I say it is no difference except the expire time, the refresh token has a long expire time and access token have a very short expire time? I could use the same way to gernetate token and pass different expire time.

Comment: You can check here.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3487991/why-does-oauth-v2-have-both-access-and-refresh-tokens

Comment: I have read this question but I think these are 2 different question. @NiravVikani I wander is the token detail in implemention. I already know why should design 2 type of token.