# which token type use in identity server 4?

Tags: identityserver4

In Identity server 4 there is two token type

1. Access token
2. Reference token

what is the difference between access token and a reference token?

which time to use the access token and which time to use the reference token?

I want to restrict the multi-login of user, which token suits?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why Does OAuth v2 Have Both Access and Refresh Tokens?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3487991/why-does-oauth-v2-have-both-access-and-refresh-tokens)

Answer (score 0):

If you use **reference** tokens, then the token is just a random string and the receiver of the token uses the reference token to ask IdentityServer about the details that this token refer to.

When you use a **JWT** token, the token itself contains all the details about who issued it, who is it for and additional claims about the owner of the token.

There are various pros/cons with using either token format.

If I am not mistaken, if you want to use **AddJwtBearer** in your API to handle tokens, then you must use the JWT format. because it does not support reference tokens.

See this [page](https://docs.duendesoftware.com/identityserver/v5/tokens/reference/) for more details.