# While sending request to Auth0 to get access token, is it possible to hide payload with secret keys which are visible?

Tags: javascript, access-token, auth0

I'm using Auth0 for sign in/sign up flow and user has possibility to update his profile information.

In order to do that I'm requesting a `token` from auth0 using URL `'https://YOUR_DOMAIN/oauth/token'`, sending in payload this sensitive information:

```
data: {
    grant_type: 'client_credentials',
    client_id: 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID',
    client_secret: 'YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET',
    audience: 'https://YOUR_DOMAIN/api/v2/'
  }
```

which is in plain text visible in Network Request browser.

This is procedure I'm following is here: https://auth0.com/docs/secure/tokens/access-tokens/get-management-api-access-tokens-for-production

So is possible to hide this payload data which contains this sensitive information? Since with this token you can manipulate users data if you know `userID`.

Or there is some other way to retrieve token from auth0 before updating profile?

Comment: This flow is for server-side only. Since it _needs_ those credentials, this request is not meant to ever be performed from client-side code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should obtain the new access token from the backend and then also update the users profile from the backend.

Your `access_token` should be encrypted and can be stored in a cookie or JWT token in the users browser. This is send on every request to your server/backend, you decrypt it and extract some of users info, including the expiration time of the token and the `refresh_token`.

If the `access_token` is expired you request a new one using the `refresh_token` from your backend to the authorization server.

If you are interested I also explain the reason for having access_token and refresh_token here: [Why Does OAuth v2 Have Both Access and Refresh Tokens?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3487991/why-does-oauth-v2-have-both-access-and-refresh-tokens/71932878#71932878)

Answer (score 1):

You should do a Client_Credentials Flow only from the backend. Then you also wouldn't have the Problem with the credentials being visible in the browser network tab.