# My access and refresh token system seems pointless (Node.JS)

Tags: node.js, express, jwt, access-token, refresh-token

I'm trying to implement access and refresh tokens when a user logs into the node.js web server via ajax requests from the web browser.

I have it so when they login, it creates a new access and refresh token and saves it to the user's cookie, access token expires in 1 hour, refresh token expires in 30 days.

Then the tokens in the cookie get authenticated when the user does something, such as views the index page (get) or wants to update their profile (post):

- If the access token is invalid, it looks to the refresh token
- If the access token is valid, it continues with the request
- If the refresh token is invalid, it sends the user back to the login page
- If refresh token is valid, it generates a new access token and a new refresh token and continues with the request

**My token verification middleware:**

```
    exports.verifyAccessToken = (redirect) => (req, res, next) => {
        const accessToken = req.cookies.accessToken;
        const refreshToken = req.cookies.refreshToken;
        log.debug("verifying, cookies:", req.cookies);

        if (!accessToken) {
            return redirect ? res.redirect("/login") : res.status(401).json({ message: 'Verification Error: Access Token missing' });
        }

        jwt.verify(accessToken, process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET, (err, decoded) => {
            if (err) {
                if (!refreshToken) {
                    return redirect ? res.redirect("/login") : res.status(400).json({ message: 'Verification Error: Access Token invalid/expired, Refresh Token missing' });
                }

                jwt.verify(refreshToken, process.env.REFRESH_TOKEN_SECRET, (err, decoded) => {
                    if (err) {
                        return redirect ? res.redirect("/login") : res.status(403).json({ message: 'Verification Error: Refresh Token invalid/expired' });
                    }
                    
                    helper.setNewAccessToken(res, decoded.email);
                    helper.setNewRefreshToken(res, decoded.email);
                    req.user = decoded;
                    next();
                });
            } else {
                req.user = decoded;
                next();
            }
        });
    };
```

Is this a valid way to handle access/refresh tokens? I just don't see the point if the refresh token gets stolen anyways, the whole thing is redundant.

Am I supposed to store the refresh token somewhere else or is it supposed to be in the cookie along with the access token?

What's the proper way to implement this? I want it so the user doesn't have to continuously log back in every hour while also making sure everything is secure.

Comment: Are you actually asking what is the purpose of refresh tokens? The answer is not so straightforward. You have to see it from the whole architecture and not just the client. You may want to check out other questions like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3487991/why-does-oauth-v2-have-both-access-and-refresh-tokens?rq=2

Comment: I'm asking what's wrong with my system of fetching refresh tokens or if I'm doing it right. I've done my due diligence and tried to research the topic and implement it myself. I'm asking for guidance on if my system is correct or not.

Answer (score 1):

Your flow is not correct as you should not be sending the access token and the refresh token together from the client side when accessing the Resource. In fact you should have different endpoints for a resource flow (using access token), auth flow (using login credentials) and a refresh flow (using the refresh token). So when client accesses the Resource, you should only be checking the access token.

At the client side, one way to store the tokens is in cookies but the access token and refresh token should be separated as much as possible. You can use httpOnly secure cookies to different endpoints so that the tokens do not get exposed. So for example the refresh token will only be accessible at the refresh endpoint using SSL and it should ideally not be accessible through javascript at client to reduce attack surface.

Comment: I'm using httpOnly: res.cookie('refreshToken', refreshToken, { httpOnly: true, secure: true, expires: expirationDate });

So the tokens are both accessed via cookies, the server has both tokens at the same time via cookies anyways. Whats the point in using two endpoints?

Comment: Two endpoints is to prevent exposure of the token during transmission. Given that the refresh token is longer lived compared to access token, you want to expose it as little as possible. Since you are sending the access token with every request, you don't want to also expose the refresh token when it is not needed right? That's why you should have a separate process to generate another access token from the refresh token.

Comment: So wait am I not supposed to be using cookies? Or are you saying I should use a cookie for the access token and send the refresh token over the request manually? Really confused

Comment: When I login, how is the web server supposed to send the tokens separately? There's only 1 request to login. Once you login, the access and refresh tokens get generated at once and then sent by setting cookies. How am I supposed to separate that? I'm confused.

Comment: Let me split it into 3 different processes. 1. Authorization: client provides login credentials and get access/refresh token from server. 2. Refresh: client provides refresh token and gets access/refresh token. 3. Resource: client provides access token and gets resource. At *client* side, you provide access token to access resource. If this fails, you get a new access token using refresh token. If not, you ask the user to login again

Comment: I understand that you mean when the user provides the token for authorization to access the web server, the tokens should be sent separately. But, the tokens are in the cookie. One endpoint is going to have access to both tokens no matter what: via req.cookies.accessToken and req.cookies.refreshToken. The server has access to both of those already.

Comment: You can set different cookies based on path. So, 1. accessToken cookie accessible to Resource path. 2. refreshToken cookie accessible to Refresh path. So, when accessing Resource path, only accessToken cookie will be sent [p.s. I understand the confusion now. In my original answer, my sending of access/refresh token refers to sending from the client side]

Comment: Thank you, is there some documentation on what to set the path to? Do you mean when I do res.cookie('accessToken', accessToken, { httpOnly: true, secure: true, expires: expirationDate }); on the web server? I don't understand what to set the paths to. This is getting even more confusing honestly.

I have it so: I login, the web server generates the tokens: res.cookie('accessToken', ..); res.cookie('refreshToken', ..); Then when the user tries to access a resource, it checks each token sequencially via req.cookies(). This happens on many routes via one middleware. Is there a code example?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257106/discussion-between-radiance-wei-qi-ong-and-aran-bins).